# SSRS grouping aggregate issue

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, aggregate

I'm creating a report that is actually 7 reports in one.  The first page needs to have a count of records of each report looking like this:

```
                 Current    Old    Total   

    Report 1     1300       1200    2500  
    Report 2     2500       1000    3500
```

I created a table with a row group and used an Expression like this to get the Current and Old values:

```
    =IIF(Fields!praccode.Value <> "DO", sum(CountDistinct(Fields!last_name.Value & Fields!first_name.Value)),0)
```

One issue that I'm having is that praccode.Value has multiple values <> "DO", so it is giving me a group count for each value where I just need one value totaling all values.  How would I get just a single count for all values <> "DO"?

Another issue I'm finding is that as I add more of these expressions the report runs slower and slower.  Is it better to create these counts directly in SQL instead of SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to evaluate the value of the **praccode** field for each record, you'll need to include it inside of the aggregate function:

```
=CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!praccode.Value <> "DO", Fields!last_name.Value & Fields!first_name.Value, NOTHING))
```

You'll need to use NOTHING as the other choice for the IIF so that it isn't counted when you want the unique values.

Every expression does take a little bit of time so any calculations that you can do with the query would help speed up the report. Your original expression that was summing a count in the same line was unnecessary since it would always be summing a single value but still making it slower.

Comment: This gave me the same result as my original expression, a count of each value that is not "DO."  I need just one count of all the values that are not "DO."

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I needed to right click on the expression box and select Add Total.  Then hide the original expression box.